# Came across this line in a css style sheet #page ul[id^=subnav]

Tags: css

first post here, apologies if I did something wrong, but I came across this...

```
#page ul[id^=subnav] { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

in a css style sheet, whats does the ^= do and is it practical to use?  Thanks for any info.

Comment: Value begins with a certain set of text: http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/ P.S. you're going to get voted down and closed I'll bet. Questions need to display a certain amount of knowledge that you can understand what you're asking and what the answer is, it seems like you don't know much about CSS. You can Google for tutorials. A question like this could be answered in 5 seconds of Googling.

Answer (score 1):

> [**W3.org - Selectors Level 3 - 6.3.2. Substring matching attribute selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)
>
> `[att^=val]` Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

In this case, the selector is looking for an element with an `id` of `page`, whose descendant `ul` element has an `id` beginning with the string "subnav".

Answer (score 0):

From **[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** about attribute selectors:

> [attr^=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value is prefixed by "value".

so basically your selector will match any `<ul>` elements whose stayed inside `#page` with an id value starting with `subnav` such as `<ul id="subnav1">`,`<ul id="subnav2">`....